# SQLite getString returning empty string

Tags: android, sqlite, select, utf-8

I have a SQLite table which contains a list of words in Spanish. Column is of VARCHAR(255) type. When I try to retrieve the strings using getString() some words return an empty string(not all). So I tried using:

```
new String(cursor.getBlob(INDEX_WORD), "UTF-8");
```

This returned a string but it contained �. Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

Apparently it was something wrong with import function of sqliteadmin. Although sqliteadmin shows the characters correctly, it actually is not in UTF-8 format. I ended up importing the data through sqlite browser. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, are you trying to get an image with getBlob(), use  new String(cursor.getString(INDEX_WORD), "UTF-8");

Comment: no, I am trying to retrieve a String. I used blob because it returns the byte[]. cursor.getString(INDEX_WORD) returns an empty string.

Comment: `getString()` does not change anything. Show the code that writes the string into the database.

Comment: I don't actually insert to data on the app, I import a csv file through sqliteadmin. which I think might be causing the problem.